# update with the latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a table as shown below:

[image]

I need to update them into the latest last_order_date, which the table can be shown as below:

[image]

I have 20000 plus records, I need a query to update them at once.

Thank you for spending your time to look at it.

Comment: Then why not delete the records which do not have the latest order date? It would definitely keep your tale in first normal form. What say?

Comment: Since you have different values for the field 'cust_id', you might want to consider scripting it with another language and manipulating results after results of SQL since it's generally recommended to avoid loops at database level.

Comment: I agree with @Rachcha - there's almost never a good reason for tables to have duplicate rows.  If this is the only information in the table, delete the extra rows.  If there's more, you may want to rethink your structure somewhat (post on the network for more focused help).  Your data is in a nicely sortable format, thankfully - is it an actual date type?

Answer (score 2):

Using join on max calculating subquery

```
UPDATE t
SET t.last_order_date =a.maxDate
FROM tableName t
INNER JOIN
 ( SELECT cust_id ,MAX(last_order_date) As maxDate
   FROM tableName GROUP BY cust_id ) a
ON a.cust_id =t.cust_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
UPDATE [table_name] 
SET    last_order_date = (SELECT Max([b].last_order_date) 
                          FROM   [table_name] [b] 
                          WHERE  [b].cust_id = [table_name].cust_id);
```

Comment: I would suggest joining to a sub-query that groups by cust_id, that way the query is run just once instead of run per row.

Comment: @TimothyWalters - I'm aware that (recent versions of at least) support this syntax, but not all RDBMSs do (I'm lookin' at you, DB2 for I); this is a valid multi-platform query, then.  Do you know if SQL Server can optimize this into the join version (I think DB2 _may_ be able to, but it's been too long and I don't have an instance)?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse given that the question was tagged with SQL Server 2008 I figure that an answer specific to that is valid. While it could be valid to provide a multi-platform answer, that means working to the lowest common denominator, great for academic answers, no so great for "use this in your real-world apps" answers. In regards to if SQL-Server may/may-not optimize this into a JOIN, I wouldn't want to rely on that as I prefer to just write good SQL to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the maximum dates in a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) using a [window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) `MAX()`, then reference the CTE in the main (`UPDATE`) statement:

```
WITH maxdates AS (
  SELECT
    last_order_date,
    actual_last_order_date = MAX(last_order_date) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id)
  FROM atable
)
UPDATE maxdates
SET last_order_date = actual_last_order_date
;
```

However, duplicating this piece of information like this doesn't seem to make much sense. You should probably consider storing `last_order_date` in a table where `cust_id` is the primary key (probably some `customers` table). Or even abandon storing it in a table and calculate it dynamically every time: 20,000 rows isn't really that much. (Unless you have serious expectations for that number to grow rapidly and soon.)