# Find last match with latest inserted name in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `PersonalInfo` having columns such as `Id, Name, Address`.

Suppose I have following data

```
1    John    US
2    Mark    UK
3    John    UK
4    David   US
```

Now when I insert following new record

```
5 John China
```

I want to update the last record having same name as the new one for example as shown here the record `3    John    UK` will be updated to `3 John China`.

When I insert the 5th record the table should be

```
1    John    US
2    Mark    UK
3    John    China
4    David   US
5    John    China
```

what sql query should I use?

Comment: Whenever insert new record I want to update previous record with same name but only the last one which matches

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942043/update-with-the-latest-date

Comment: Please, elaborate your question. Which is the final estate of the table when you insert 5 John China?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Id is auto-incremented, it would be the highest value for that Name and Address combination.

```
UPDATE PersonalInfo
SET Address = 'US'
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(Id)
FROM PersonalInfo
WHERE Name = 'John'
AND Address = 'UK'
)
```

Comment: Please update your nearly correct answer: remove the Address from the WHERE predicate. Just take the last record from John, whatever the address is, and replace it.

Comment: after insert the max Id will be 5 but I want to update second max Id

Comment: @Twix do you want all records to be updated to have the new address for a give inserted name?  For example, when 'John','China' gets inserted, do you want Id 3 and 1 to also be updated to have 'China' as the address or just Id = 3?

Comment: Do the `UPDATE` before the insert, or add to the `WHERE` clause to exclude the new row. You could add `AND Id != (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM PersonalInfo)` to the `WHERE` clause (the second one).